# Use trigger to INSERT new row to one table from another table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables

**Favourites Table**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| FavouritesID | CompanyID | CustomerID | ProfilePhoto | CompanyName |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Profile Table**

```
-------------------------------------------
| CompanyID | CompanyName | ProfilePhoto  |
-------------------------------------------
|      1    | Nike        |http://loca..  |
|      2    | Adidas      |http://loca..  |
|      3    | PaulSmith   |http://loca..  |
-------------------------------------------
```

I want to INSERT `CompanyName` and `ProfilePhoto` into the Favourites Table using the `CompanyID`

So when a row is inserted to Favourites table ex CompanyID=1, the `CompanyName=Nike`
and `ProfilePhoto=htpp://local...` will be inserted to favourites table, getting info from the Profile Table.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Favourites` BEFORE INSERT ON `Favourites`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Favourites SET ProfilePhoto = (SELECT ProfilePhoto FROM Profile WHERE NEW.CompanyID = CompanyID);
END
```

What are the errors in my code? It does not work

Comment: What you want to do just doesn't make sense, and neither does your attempt to implement the trigger. When you want to know the `ProfilePhoto` of a `Favourite`, `JOIN` in your `Profile` table.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to store the same data twice?  I was always taught not to store the same information in multiple tables.  If you need a favorites table why not just store:

```
| FavouritesID | CompanyID | CustomerID |
```

Then if you need other information from the profile table find it with company ID from the favorites table

Answer (score 0):

I think U can use **AFTER INSERT** .............

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON orders
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN

   -- Find username of person performing the INSERT into the table
   SELECT user INTO v_username
   FROM dual;

   -- Insert record into audit table
   INSERT INTO orders_audit
   ( order_id,
     quantity,
     cost_per_item,
     total_cost,
     username )
   VALUES
   ( :new.order_id,
     :new.quantity,
     :new.cost_per_item,
     :new.total_cost,
     v_username );

END;
```